# Vue Error Message: Do not mutate vuex store outside of mutation handler

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I reviewed the docs and got several Vue Projects smoothly running with Vuex, but this error is confusing.

state.js

```
return {
     articles: [],
     currentArticle: null,
}
```

mutations.js

```
addArticles(state, articles) {
  state.articles.push(...articles);
}
```

Function that commits inside my Vue Component:

```
  async created() {
    const recentArticles = [];

    const querySnapshot = await this.$firestore.collection('fl_content').limit(5).get();

    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
      recentArticles.push({id: doc.id, ...doc.data()});
    });

    this.$store.commit('articles/addArticles', recentArticles);
  }
```

I also tried to make a copy of the array to manipulate, but that didn't help.

Errors:

```
vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Error in callback for watcher "function () { return this._data.$$state }": "Error: [vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers."

vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1888 Error: [vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers.
    (found in <Root>)
```

Comment: I don't think the error is coming from the code you've posted. That said, it looks like you're creating an array of arrays. Is that what you intended? Did you maybe mean `state.articles.push(...articles);`.

Comment: Can you also share the error?

Comment: @evolon yes done.

Comment: @skirtle yes fixed that slipped through but the error is definetly from that code its the only store related code I took everything else out already.

Comment: @Badgy, How did you included `mutations.js` inside `state.js`?

Comment: I use quasar and have them imported into a index.js, with console logs I assured that the method is called correctly and all

Answer (score 0):

This is because, when you do your first commit

```
this.$store.commit('articles/addArticles', recentArticles);
```

a shallow copy of recentArticles is saved in Vuex. and now if you change recentArticles in component it will generate this error.

so the solution would be to create Deep copy of recentArticles while committing

```
this.$store.commit('articles/addArticles', [...recentArticles]);
```

though there are many ways to create Deep Copy, but this is the simplest one.